# How to set up Subversion over HTTP

Tags: svn, http

I'm relatively new to Subversion. I'm familiar with the basic concepts and have used simple checkout/update/commit commands, but nothing more. I am starting a new project and would like to use Subversion.

I work from a lot of different computers, so having a local svn repo doesn't make much sense. I do have access to a server. I do not have admin rights to that server, but I do have a `public_html` directory that is world-readable. I figured I would just create the repo somewhere underneath my `public_html` directory and check it out using the HTTP protocol.

I created the repo in `~/public_html/myrepo`, successfully checked it out on that machine, and verified that the repo was accessible via a web browser at `http://myserver.myschool.edu/~myusername/myrepo`.

Then I tried checking it out to my local machine using `svn co http://myserver.myschool.edu/~myusername/myrepo`, but I got the following message.

```
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://myserver.myschool.edu/~myusername/myrepo/'; please relocate
```

I'm guessing I took a naive approach and that I'm missing something. Any ideas? The server hosting the repo is running Fedora Linux, and I don't have admin rights. Also, I would like the repo to be accessible without a password.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you create a repo? What did you mean by "successfully checked it out on that machine" - are you talking about server? Maybe you are messing local repo with server repo.

Comment: Check this by contents: server repo has folders /conf, /db, /hooks, etc

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: @Pmod, I created the repo on the server (Linux) using the 'svnadmin create' and 'svn import' commands. When I checked it in the web browser, it does indeed have the /conf, /db, etc directories.

Comment: @Zellus, I want to check out the code to a variety of computers, running everything from Ubuntu to Red Hat to Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Occasionally configuration rights are granted via `.htaccess` put in your public_html. Apache must load the module dav_svn in order to service your subversion repository. Not an easy task to setup subversion over http without administration privileges. Maybe your admin is willing to give a hand.

Free hosted subversion services as pointed out by other posters might be an option as well.

Comment: I was beginning to fear that this was the case. I'm not concerned that the sysadmin isn't helpful, just that I have to go through the sysadmin whenever I want to make a change. Assuming the 'dav_svn' module is installed, is there a way that I can configure svn repos within my home directory (since I cannot modify the global config files)? If so, then the solution is simple--have the sysadmin verify that 'dav_svn' is installed, and from then on I'll manage my repo(s).

Comment: He shall create the repository once and grant you access privileges. After that you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the easiest way is to use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). The Standard edition is free for commercial use.

Comment: i second that... I recently installed VisualSVN Server on my server and am now using it with Ankh Svn plugin for Visual Studio and it works great..

Comment: @sassyboy, Sorry I was not more specific. The server hosting the repo is running Fedora Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out http://www.origo.ethz.ch/ to see if it meets your needs..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is VisualSvn Server, but that's Windows only. For a cross-platform equivalent, [Collabnet's Edge](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/redhat.html) is the way to go. its a fully-set up stack of Apache, Subversion and ViewVC, that link is to the RedHat install.